# C++ CLI Serial port missing data received

Tags: visual-studio, serial-port, c++-cli

I have a problem with missing data in serialport. When I run first time code all data is correct. But every next time data is missing.

For example :

First time : 01 00 00 00 01 0A CA - CORRECT

Second time : 0A CA - MISSING DATA

Third time : CA - MISSING DATA

```
private: System::Void serialPort1_DataReceived(System::Object^  sender, System::IO::Ports::SerialDataReceivedEventArgs^  e) {

                  numbytes = serialPort1->BytesToRead;
                  encodedBytes = gcnew array<Byte>(numbytes);
                  for (ck = 0; ck < numbytes; ck++){
                      encodedBytes[ck] = serialPort1->ReadByte();
                  }
             this->Invoke(gcnew EventHandler(this,&MyForm3::SetTextCallback));
    }
    private: System::Void SetTextCallback(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e){
   textBox9->Text = "";
     for (ck = 0; ck <numbytes; ck++){
         this->textBox9->AppendText((encodedBytes[ck].ToString("X2")));
    }
    numbytes = 0;
    ck = 0;

    }
```

Comment: How fast are these 7 byte messages arriving? Is it possible that the second message is arriving while the first message is in the middle of being added to the text box?

Comment: It's very slow. The time is about 10 seconds. Data arrives have different (random) lengths ... but only first time the data is fully

Comment: `textBox9->Text = "";` prevents AppendText() from doing anything sensible.  It makes you only see the last few bytes that were received.  Usually just one or two, serial ports are slow.  So the "missing" bytes were not actually missing, they just got overpainted very quickly.  You'll have to rethink this.